# How to print Airflow time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

[Need this info in the log as a print statement click for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5YKm.png)

Comment: Do you need this info as part of a task in the dag at the nd ? Or query from outside with api its good?

Comment: Yes, both the way I need Like as a part of a task and Xcom value also.

Comment: do you want the give dag duration in every task ? specific task that check the duration until this task ? part of the log or simply print it ? if you can add more details to your question it would be great

Comment: I have added an image in my question this is all the dag-related info I need can you pls provide this info in a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to get the duration of a DAG in a task in the DAG itself, then you need to put it as last task and need to understand there will be a little difference (cause the duration task is part of the DAG)

Here, an example of simple DAG that in the last task I calculate the duration and put it in the XCOM.

There is a bit difference also between XCOM and Airflow UI because rounding of the numbers.

[image]

[image]

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context
from airflow.sensors.time_delta import TimeDeltaSensor
from airflow.utils import timezone

with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval=None,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["test"],
) as dag:

    @task
    def task1():
        print("task1")

    sleep_task = TimeDeltaSensor(
        task_id="sleep",
        delta=timedelta(seconds=3),
        mode='reschedule'
    )

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def duration_task():
        context = get_current_context()
        dag_run = context["dag_run"]
        execution_date = dag_run.execution_date
        now = timezone.make_aware(datetime.utcnow())
        duration = now - execution_date
        return {
            "duration": str(duration),
            "start_time": str(dag_run.execution_date),
            "end_time": str(now)
        }

    (task1() >> sleep_task >> duration_task())
```